# I want to install complete software using command line for test automation

Tags: cmd, command, installation, ui-automation

Let take as one example, I want to install Java on my machine using the command line so I just type below command as administrator:

```
start /w jre-7u51-windows-x64.exe
```

I also tried below command in order to get help from command line

```
jre-7u51-windows-x64.exe /?
```

Now a pop up appears in which we need to click the "install" button.

I don't want any user interaction and I want complete installation using command line.

Is there any way to automate the install button click?

If any other technologies available for this also let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `/s` silent installation switch.

---

Source [How do I arrange a silent (unattended) Java installation?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml)

> **Command-Line Installation**
>
> The Java SE 7 Windows Offline Installer command has the following syntax:
>
> `<jre>.exe [/s] [INSTALLDIR=<drive>:\<JRE_install_path>] [STATIC=1]
>   [WEB_JAVA=0/1] [WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=VH/H/M] [SPONSORS=0]`
>
> Note:
>
> - .exe is the single executable installer for the JRE.
>     /s, if used, indicates a silent installation.
>     INSTALLDIR, if used, specifies the drive and path of the JRE. If INSTALLDIR is not specified, the installation will go into C:\Program
>     Files\java\jre (default location).
> - STATIC=1, if used, specifies a static installation. For more information about static installations, see Static Installation in
>     Patch-in-Place and Static JRE Installation.
> - WEB_JAVA=0, if used, disables any Java application from running in the browser.
> - WEB_JAVA=1, the default, enables Java applications in
>     the browser. This field is available as of the 7u10 release. For more
>     information, see Setting the Security Level of the Java Client.
> - WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL, if used, sets the security level of unsigned Java apps running in a browser. The possible values for this
>     field are VH (very high), H (high, the default), or M (medium). This
>     field is available as of the 7u10 release. For more information, see
>     Setting the Security Level of the Java Client.
> - SPONSORS=0, if used, entirely bypasses sponsor offers such as browser add-ons. This field is available as of the 7u55 release. Note
>     that sponsor offers, and therefore this functionality, is only
>     applicable to online 32 bit JRE installers and Auto Update mechanisms.

---

Source [JRE Installer Options](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml)

> **Installation Configurations**
>
> Example 1
>
> Suppose the JRE installer is
>   jre-7-windows-i586.exe and you want to install the following
>   configuration:
>
> - Perform a Windows Installation
> - Install the JRE core, additional fonts, colors, and Soundbank
>
> The command to install the above mentioned configuration is as
>   follows: jre-7-windows-i586.exe /s
>
> Example 2
>
> Suppose the JRE installer is jre-7-windows-i586.exe and you
>   want to install the following configuration:
>
> - Perform a Windows Offline Installation and install the JRE on D drive at java\jre
> - Have all features of the JRE installed
>
> The command to install the above mentioned configuration is as
>   follows: jre-7-windows-i586.exe /s INSTALLDIR=D:\java\jre
>
> Note: To keep the MS-DOS window open, until the installation of Java
>   is complete use the start /w command as follows: start /w
>   jre-7-windows-i586.exe /s

---

**"I want the command in terms of general use for other applications not only java"**

Note that there is no general solution to this problem, since there are many different types of installer and installers for different programs  will likely have different "popups" (and may even change when new version of the program are released).

Read the whole of following link for a full discussion of how difficult this is.

---

[Unattended/Silent Installation Switches for Windows Apps](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php)

> The goal of this document is to collect instructions for performing unattended / silent installations of many popular application installers. Such instructions are useful for automating these installations.

The document includes instructions for silent installation using many different installer types.

It also includes a suggestion for a tool [AutoIt](http://www.hiddensoft.com/autoit3/):

> AutoIt can  simulate key presses and mouse clicks, following a script customarily named with a .aut or a .au3 extension.
>
> Most installers have a sufficiently simple and consistent interface that a very short AutoIt script suffices to automate their installation.

...

> AutoIt scripts do have drawbacks.
>
> First, you must be careful when upgrading to new releases of an application, since the installer's UI may have changed.
>
> More worryingly, AutoIt scripts are theoretically unreliable because they do not let you determine when a sub-process has exited. You can tell when AutoIt itself exits, but that is not the same thing at all. For example, an installer's last window might disappear while the installer was still working. Your master script, waiting only for the AutoIt executable, would then proceed, starting another installation or rebooting the machine.

There are other such tools available.

Comment: Thanks david for answer but i want the command in terms of general use like any other applications also not only java do you any idea about it then please share it.                                                                              i just completed java installation using python's pywinauto but for this i need to install python so if you have any idea using cmd then please share it